# Randomness Comparison Experiment

Tags: random, statistics, probability

I have a drug analysis experiment that need to generate a value based on given drug database and set of `1000` random experiments.

The `original database` looks like this where the number in the columns represent the rank for the drug. This is a simplified version of `actual database`, the `actual database` will have more `Drug` and more `Gene`.

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Genes | DrugA | DrugB |
+-------+-------+-------+
| A     |     1 |     3 |
| B     |     2 |     1 |
| C     |     4 |     5 |
| D     |     5 |     4 |
| E     |     3 |     2 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

A score is calculated based on user's input: `A` and `C`, using the following formula:

```
# Compute Function
# ['A','C'] as array input

computeFunction(array) {
    # do some stuff with the array ...
}
```

The formula used will be same for any provided value.

For randomness test, each set of experiment requires the algorithm to provide randomized values of `A` and `C`, so both `A` and `C` can be having any number from `1` to `5`

Now I have two methods of selecting value to generate the `1000` sets for P-Value calculation, but I would need someone to point out if there is one better than another, or if there is any method to compare these two methods.

**Method 1**

Generate `1000` randomized database based on given database input shown above, meaning all the table should contain different set of value pair.

Example for `1` database from `1000` randomized database:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Genes | DrugA | DrugB |
+-------+-------+-------+
| A     |     2 |     3 |
| B     |     4 |     4 |
| C     |     3 |     2 |
| D     |     1 |     5 |
| E     |     5 |     1 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Next we perform `computeFunction()` with new `A` and `C` value.

**Method 2**

Pick any random gene from `original database` and use it as a newly randomized gene value.

For example, we pick the values from `E` and `B` as a new value for `A` and `C`.

From `original database`, `E` is 3, `B` is 2.

So, now `A` is 3, `C` is 2. Next we perform `computeFunction()` with new `A` and `C` value.

**Summary**

Since both methods produce completely randomized input, therefore it seems to me that it will produce similar `1000-value` outcome. Is there any way I could prove they are similar?

Comment: You have 5 genes, 5 DrugA's, and 5 DrugB's.  Why not enumerate all 5^3 = 125 combinations rather than using randomness?  If you're willing to take 1000 samples, that gives you 8 replications without risk of overlooking some combo due to the randomness.

Comment: the fact in the database is that there are more than just 10k genes or 100 drugs, so the combination would take a very long time to get the result

Comment: Then *that's* what you should be describing in your question.